# Session dissapears after refresh PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I want do store multiple values each time page is loaded. But my session array is not working, it's acting like a simple array.

```
session_start();

...some code...

$_SESSION['a'] = $input_value;
print_r($_SESSION); //here I have only 1 variable
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$_SESSION['a']` every time with the new input_value. So there only will be 1 value.

Comment: and how to not overwrite @Michel?

Comment: See the answer from @Baracuda

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What is not working then?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: You use your Session['a'] some where as a string then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not creating an array, try the code below

```
$_SESSION['a'][] = $input_value;
```